# Cambiar string a array

Tags: python, python-3.x, array

Estoy buscando una forma de convertir un string tal cual a array simplemente cambiando el tipo de la variable.

Este es mi string:

```
[
  [ 'A', 'G', 'not_a' ], [ 'A', 'H', 'not_a' ],
  [ 'A', 'I', 'not_a' ], [ 'A', 'a' ],
  [ 'B', 'G', 'not_a' ], [ 'B', 'H', 'not_a' ],
  [ 'B', 'I', 'not_a' ], [ 'B', 'a' ],
  [ 'C', 'not_a' ],      [ 'D', 'G', 'not_a' ],
  [ 'D', 'H', 'not_a' ], [ 'D', 'I', 'not_a' ],
  [ 'D', 'a' ],          [ 'E', 'not_a' ],
  [ 'F', 'G', 'not_a' ], [ 'F', 'H', 'not_a' ],
  [ 'F', 'I', 'not_a' ], [ 'F', 'a' ]
]
```

Cuando pruebo con métodos como `split()` se me genera de la siguiente forma:

```
['[', '[', "'A',", "'G',", "'not_a'", '],', '[', "'A',", "'H',", "'not_a'", '],', '[', "'A',", "'I',", "'not_a'", '],', '[', "'A',", "'a'", '],', '[', "'B',", "'G',", "'not_a'", '],', '[', "'B',", "'H',", "'not_a'", '],', '[', "'B',", "'I',", "'not_a'", '],', '[', "'B',", "'a'", '],', '[', "'C',", "'not_a'", '],', '[', "'D',", "'G',", "'not_a'", '],', '[', "'D',", "'H',", "'not_a'", '],', '[', "'D',", "'I',", "'not_a'", '],', '[', "'D',", "'a'", '],', '[', "'E',", "'not_a'", '],', '[', "'F',", "'G',", "'not_a'", '],', '[', "'F',", "'H',", "'not_a'", '],', '[', "'F',", "'I',", "'not_a'", '],', '[', "'F',", "'a'", ']', ']']
```

Porque entiendo que cada carácter del string lo toma como un elemento distinto a la hora de crear el array. Soy novata en esto. Solamente quiero cambiarle el tipo.

Comment: Python no ofrece nada para lograr eso. Parte del trabajo de un programador, es hayar la forma de resolver algo usando los materiales de construccion del lenguaje ;)

Comment: @CandidMoe quiza para Python no sea una cadena, pero el op quiere transmitir que lo que esta entre las comillas guardado en una variable es lo que muestra en la pregunta.

Comment: @DanteS. Correcto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un string es un array prácticamente, porque contiene una lista de caracteres. En tu caso, lo que tienes es un string que contiene una lista de caracteres con la sintaxis del tipo de dato `list` de Python. Python puede entender el texto que contenga la sintaxis de un tipo de dato de Python y convertirlo en un tipo de dato real de Python. Puedes hacerlo usando el modulo `ast` de Python, así:

```py
import ast

string="""[
  [ 'A', 'G', 'not_a' ], [ 'A', 'H', 'not_a' ],
  [ 'A', 'I', 'not_a' ], [ 'A', 'a' ],
  [ 'B', 'G', 'not_a' ], [ 'B', 'H', 'not_a' ],
  [ 'B', 'I', 'not_a' ], [ 'B', 'a' ],
  [ 'C', 'not_a' ],      [ 'D', 'G', 'not_a' ],
  [ 'D', 'H', 'not_a' ], [ 'D', 'I', 'not_a' ],
  [ 'D', 'a' ],          [ 'E', 'not_a' ],
  [ 'F', 'G', 'not_a' ], [ 'F', 'H', 'not_a' ],
  [ 'F', 'I', 'not_a' ], [ 'F', 'a' ]
]"""
result = ast.literal_eval(string)

print(type(result), result, sep="\n")
```

Resultado:

```
<class 'list'>
[['A', 'G', 'not_a'], ['A', 'H', 'not_a'], ['A', 'I', 'not_a'], ['A', 'a'], ['B', 'G', 'not_a'], ['B', 'H', 'not_a'], ['B', 'I', 'not_a'], ['B', 'a'], ['C', 'not_a'], ['D', 'G', 'not_a'], ['D', 'H', 'not_a'], ['D', 'I', 'not_a'], ['D', 'a'], ['E', 'not_a'], ['F', 'G', 'not_a'], ['F', 'H', 'not_a'], ['F', 'I', 'not_a'], ['F', 'a']]
```

Comment: Tambien podria ser sintaxis json y, por lo tanto, conviene mas usar el modulo json. Todo depende del origen de la cadena. Yo creo que deberias de reflejar eso en tu respuesta.

Comment: De todas formas, no creo que sea buena idea dar una respuesta. El OP vino con este problema por que pensaba que Python le serviria la solucion en un plato y no fue así. No tiene pinta de que haya investigado o intentado algo mas allá de ver que ofrecia el lenguaje.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con que también se puede usando el modulo json, pero tendría que hacer pasos extras, como el de convertir el string a la sintaxis de un diccionario de Python, para que el parse de json pueda entenderlo y después sacar el string del diccionario. Con el parse de Python es más rápido. 
En cuanto las intenciones de OP las desconozco. Sentí que es una pregunta genuina porque recuerdo habérmela planteado en su momento, entonces me pareció correcto responder.

Comment: Nope, un json que se conforma unicamente por un array es un json valido. En cuanto a las intenciones del OP, tampoco las se, pero no podes asumir que se esforzó lo suficiente sin ver un intento genuino. Si, la pregunta es genuina, pero por que el OP no se avivó de que Python no ofrece su solucion de forma directa, si no que tiene que crearla. Por eso le dije "parte del trabajo de un programador es resolver algo usando los materiales que ofrece el lenguaje"

Comment: Creo que es la mejor alternativa dadas las circunstancias. Una solución Python puro sería básicamente reescribir `ast`. Es entretenido porque es un rompecabezas que solo puede existir en tu cerebro hasta hacerse código. No creo que sea lo que busca.

Comment: @DanteS. Disculpa mí ignorancia con respecto a la investigación de como resolver el problema. Soy novata en esto y tienes razón no hice una investigación tan profunda como debí hacerlo. Pensé que sería mejor preguntar para recibir orientación. Lamentablemente no me sé todas las respuestas ni tampoco conozco todas las herramientas para idear una resolución de cualquier problemática. Gracias por tu comentario, lo tendré en cuenta en el futuro. Saludos.

Comment: @VSacudato entiendo. Te aclaro que este no es un sitio de orientación, si no para resolver dudas concretas. El problema no fue por que no investigaste, si no por que pensaste que Python te ofrecería la solución así nomás (aparentemente). Una parte es la investigación, pero cuando tu escenario es tan poco frecuente, toca construir con los materiales de construcción que puedas encontrar, por que lo prefabricado no siempre satisfacerá tus necesidades. No todo en programación es investigar.

Comment: Por cierto, veo que tenés suficiente reputación para hablar por el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol). La proxima que tengas una duda que no encaje en el sitio, podés preguntar ahí.