# Dar formato de cadena (forma polinomica) a dos listas numericas

Tags: python, operador

La siguiente funcion es para realizar el producto entre dos polinomios,la misma funciona..Esta funcion al final tiene dos listas importantes que serian el resultado del producto. En la lista prod se guardan los coeficientes del producto y en la lista expp se guardan los exponentes del producto..Teniendo esta lista como puedo retornar una sola cadena fucionando ambas listas? Por ejemplo
(3x^3+5x)*(2x+1) = **6x^4+10x^2+3x^3+5x --> Esta cadena es a lo que quiero llegar**

lista prod --> [5,10,3,6] coeficientes del producto

lista expp --> [1,2,3,4] exponente del producto

```
def mulpol(pol1,pol2):
  auxcoef = [0] * (len(pol1)*len(pol2))
  auxexp = [0] * len(auxcoef)
  cnt = 0
  while cnt < len(auxcoef):
    for i in range(len(pol1)):
      for j in range(len(pol2)):
        auxcoef[cnt] = pol1[i]*pol2[j]
        auxexp[cnt] = i + j
        cnt = cnt + 1
  cont = 0
#Para sacar cantidad de terminos nulos
  for i in range(len(auxcoef)):
    if auxcoef[i] != 0:
      cont = cont + 1
  prod = [0] * cont
  expp = [0] * cont
  contador = 0
  for i in range(len(auxcoef)):
    if auxcoef[i] == 0:
      continue
    else:
      prod[contador] = auxcoef[i]
      expp[contador] = auxexp[i]
      contador = contador + 1
  for i in range(len(prod)):
    print(prod[i],"x^",expp[i])
```

Comment: Hace un tiempo hice un evaluador de expreisones algebraicas, puedes adaptarlo a lo que requieres. [Aqui tienes la respuesta que hice](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/508399/183782)

Answer (score 0):

Recomendación: desglosa el problema.

Puedes hacer una función que se encargue de darle formato a un solo término, así:

```
def format(coef : int, exp : int) -> str:
    if (coef == 0):
        return ""

    if (exp == 0):
        return str(coef)
    
    result = ""

    if (exp >= 1 and abs(coef) != 1):
        result += str(abs(coef))

    result += "x"

    if (exp > 1):
        result += f"^{exp}"

    return result
```

Ahora es tan simple como unir cada parte:

```
def formatPoli(coefs, exps):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(coefs)):
        formatted = format(coefs[i], exps[i])
        sign = "+" if coefs[i] >= 0 else "-"

        if len(formatted):
            result += f"{sign} {formatted} "

    return result
```

Nota que faltan verificaciones. Se espera que haya la misma cantidad de exponentes que coeficientes.

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##dZLBisIwEIbveYp/czJYoa4Ki1CfYQ97Exe6a6qBmpYkgiI@e3eS1NJqN6fpP/98k5m0vrpjpRdNU5jqBHetlT5AnerKOHyd61IytpcFisqccjf5rSheQ2mXQF7qGArMNrDOrBnoqALRlmVIRdT8MdKdjQbnrLN5wriLaAEiQoLFjD2XDtkLYZNhjlzvkf/YWIQ3kgbQUDrNArezCcaGWX55Rv@DKfj3jfJ3/iCES8d8f1@fValCLxvWZVtYfxT/TWYo2iRMrg9yUkodi0SveQQ6uaey3mPYrdpFNgWic1t10J4/5X6Wh9GvKoUsrQSftXdvx/U9uxa9ts9z3zz5jlvnvWN8Caw29Gu0zEma0CuLoTYf0WYkzsfE1Yu4SrB8Fklb@GcNA9P8W6p8Jy2BZ/iSdMf8stpcGtIULBN87IZ3fnk7wZrmDw).

Answer (score 0):

Usando comprensión de listas:

```
coef = [5,10,3,6]
exp =  [1,2,3,4]

producto = '+'.join(f"{coef[i]}x^{exp[i]}" for i in range(len(coef) - 1, -1, -1))
print(producto)
```

produce

```
6x^4+3x^3+10x^2+5x^1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Explicación:

La dos listas son de igual largos, las puedo recorrer en paralelo con un `for` para sacar coeficiente y exponente. Como las listas vienen ordenadas de menor a mayor exponente, las recorro desde el final hacia el principio usando un `range(len(coef) - 1, -1, -1)`

Por cada indice, recupero exponente y coeficiente, formateandolos con *f-string*

```
f"{coef[i]}x^{exp[i]}"
```

Obtengo con eso una lista de terminos que uno con `join()`, agregando el separador "+" entre ellos.

Comment: Solo para agregar, si queres podes usar la función zip, que toma iterables (como listas), los convierte en iteradores y los recorre en paralelo hasta que se agote uno de ellos (detalle poco importante si ambas listas son del mismo largo)

Comment: @DanteS. Parte del proceso es aprender cuando usar una pala y cuando una retroexcavadora. La capacidad de distinguir entre uno y otro caso distingue al buen profesional del mediocre, google-dependiente, bueno para nada.

Comment: Buena metafora. Pero lo que dije fue usar la retroescavadora en el escenario correcto. Ademas, no llego a entender al 100% la relacion con mi comentario.

Comment: @DanteS. Como que hay muchos dependiendo de librerías para solucionar los problemas más triviales. Estupendo. ¿Qué pasa cuando no hay una librería para la necesidad específica? Plop!!! Fin del camino, nunca aprendieron a solucionar nada por si mismo; se limitaron al copy-paste de stackoverflow.

Comment: @DanteS. No tiene que ver especificamente contigo, es sólo una rabieta general.

Comment: Ya veo. Te doy la razón en ello. Yo dependo parcialmente de librerias, peeero creo que podria solucionar algunas cosas sin necesitar librerias. Digo, no podria recrear una libreria de GUI que sea bien hecha, pero podria usar una de base para crear mis propios widgets por ejemplo.

Comment: Esta pregunta es un ejemplo de lo que dices: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/567787/158880 Por ello no le di respuesta a ese usuario, por que vi que limitó su esfuerzo a investigar unicamente lo que ya Python traia resuelto.